# How do i make php retrieve mysql faster dynamically?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql

right now I'm learning how to make a web app that has a button function. When the button function is click it retrieves data from a sever and then prints it out in a div. The data is only one row. But I can't spam the button because every button click does not retrieve the data right away. It would take a lot of clicks before a new data is retrieve. Is it the way I'm implementing it?

Heres my code:

```
 connection.php
.
.
.

 // Create connection
  $conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
  // Check connection
  if ($conn->connect_error) {
      die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
  }
```

mysql.php

```
<?php
require_once("connection.php");

$sql = "SELECT applename, appletype, applequantity, appleprice FROM 
drugs";
$result = $conn->query($sql);
$numOfRows = $result->num_rows;
$randomNum = rand(1, $numOfRows);

$sql = "SELECT applename, appletype, drugquantity, drugdirection FROM drugs 
LIMIT $randomNum,1";
$result = $conn->query($sql);

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
 // output data of each row
 while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
     echo "<div>
            <span>"  .$row["drugname"]." </span>
            <span>"  .$row["drugstrength"]." </span>
            <span>  #".$row["drugquantity"]." </span>
            <p>".$row["drugdirection"]." </p>
          </div>";
 }
}

else {
 echo "0 results";
}
  $result->close();
  $conn->close();
?>
```

my .js file has a button that when clicks performs this function

```
function dataRetrive(){
    console.log("php");
    $('#div1').load("mysql.php");
  }
```

Any help is appreciated. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Are you worried about users spamming the button and making multiple DB requests?

Comment: You can disable the button when it is clicked and enable again when the process is finished.

Comment: I would actually like for it to be able to be spamable.